# Node fires 'close' for spawned external application immediately (macOS only)

Tags: node.js, electron, spawn

My Electron application needs to open an external program and wait for it to be closed before reacting again. In Windows this works fine, but macOS has some problems.

So my code for apple is

```
const cp = require('child_process');
let child;
child = cp.exec('open -a Keynote \"'+pathToFile+'\"'), function(error, stdout, stderr){
    if(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
child.on('close', function () {
    //do something when external application is closed
}
```

The problem is, that for some reason the process sends the `close` event immediately after the application is launched. Is there any way to monitor if Keynote is still opened in macOS, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found out. If anyone stumbles into the same Problem: It needs to be opened with `-W`Parameter. So

```
cp.exec('open -a Keynote \"'+pathToFile+'\"' +' -W')
```

does the trick.